# angular2-multiselect onFilterDeSelectAll not working as expected, Deselect filter All text not coming upon filter

Tags: angular, angular-material2

We are using angular2-multiselect using angular2-multiselect-dropdown': "4.6.3" version

These options available in https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/v/4.6.3

onFilterSelectAll - Callback event fired when the list is filtered and all filtered items are selected with select all filtered items checkbox. Example : (onFilterSelectAll)="onFilterSelectAll($event)"
onFilterDeSelectAll - Callback event fired when the list is filtered and all filtered items are de-selected with de-select all filtered items checkbox. Example : (onFilterDeSelectAll)="onFilterDeSelectAll($event)"

And added a dropdownsettings for this as filterUnSelectAllText to display label

But upon filter the dropdown data, we are not able to see the Label itself

Whats is the reason of not working and is there anything needs to update in any of settings or files?

HTML

```
<angular2-multiselect class="teamSelect" [attr.id]="teaamboardDropDownId"
                        [data]="teamboards" [(ngModel)]="selectedTeams" [settings]="dropdownSettingsTeams"
                        (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
                        (onSelectAll)="onSelectAllTeams($event)" (onDeSelectAll)="onDeselectAllTeams($event)"
                        (onFilterSelectAll)="onFilterSelectAll($event)"
                        (onFilterDeSelectAll)="onFilterDeSelectAll($event)">
                    </angular2-multiselect>
```

dropdownsettings in the component.ts

```
this.dropdownsettings = {
  singleselection: false,
  text: 'select',
  enableSearchFilter: true,
  enableFilterSelectAll: true,
  filterUnSelectAllText: 'Unselect'
  searchBy: ['itemName']
}
```